# Why is the weak* convergence on $\operatorname{Hom}(X,\mathbb{K})$ metrisable if $X$ is separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Assume that $X$ is a separable normed space over $\mathbb{K}\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$. (i.e. it contains a countable dense subset) and $X':=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(X,\mathbb{K})$. Let $K_{R}(0)\subset X'$ be the closed ball of radius $R$ around $0$. The paper I am reading claims there exists a metric on $K_{R}(0)$ in which a sequence $(x'_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, where $\forall i:x'_{i}\in K_{R}(0)$, converges against $x'\in K_{R}(0)$ if and only if $(x'_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges weak*ly against $x'$.

Comment: In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253287/if-x-is-separable-then-b-x-is-metrizable-for-the-weak-topology?rq=1) question a proof is given.

Comment: @G.Chiusole thanks.